# Request body logging with ContentCachingRequestWrapper in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I have a Spring controller that I want to audit, i.e. I want to log the raw request, raw response and set some MDC properties that should be derived from the request. The request contains a field that should be omitted if present.

Since `InputStream`s from `ServletRequest`s can only be read once, I'm using `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

My solution is the following, **which works perfectly fine**:

```java
@Component
public class MyAuditingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        try {
            JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(wrappedRequest.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
            MDC.put("myProperty", json.findValue("myProperty").asText();
            //replace other property in json with placeholder
            log.info(json.toString());
            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
        } finally {
            log.info(new String(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray(), wrappedResponse.getCharacterEncoding()));
            wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```java
[...]
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> doSomething(final HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    
    MyBean mybean = objectMapper.readValue(((ContentCachingRequestWrapper) servletRequest).getContentAsByteArray(), MyBean.class);
    // further processing
}
```

This setup works as it should, but I have multiple problems with this:

1. The request JSON is deserialized twice: in my Filter and in my Controller
2. My Controller is now dependent on my Filter as it requires a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`
3. I cannot use `@RequestBody MyBean myBean` as parameter in my Controller and avoid deserializing the request JSON by myself since Spring MVC `HttpMessageConverter`s want to read from the `InputStream` and are not compatible with `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

Is there anything I can do about those points? One partial solution for 2. and 3. could be to log request and response after `filterChain.doFilter()` but then I'm not able to set the MDC property.